# DisplayApplicationPicker not showing open with prompt

Tags: c#, windows, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I'm creating a Xamarin Forms application (currently only UWP) where I want to open an PDF file from the local storage. In the UWP project I receive the file path form the Xamarin Portable Project. I use the following function to open the Open With Prompt.

```
 public void OpenFileWith(string path)
 {
     Task.Run(async () =>
     {
         var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(path);

         if (file != null)
         {
             var options = new LauncherOptions();
             options.DisplayApplicationPicker = true;
             var success = await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file, options);

             if (success)
             {
                 //File Launched
             }
             else
             {
                 //File Launch Failed
             }
         }
      });
  }
```

I think I've done everything correct according to the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcheroptions#Windows_System_LauncherOptions_DisplayApplicationPicker). When I don't add the LauncherOptions the file opens correctly in the default selected Application.

Is there something I'm missing. Permissions maybe? I know the documentation has a remark "This property is only implemented on Desktop devices.". I'm testing on a Desktop (Windows 10 via VMWare)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
    public async Task OpenFileWithAsync(string path)
    {
        var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(path);

        if (file != null)
        {
            var options = new LauncherOptions();
            options.DisplayApplicationPicker = true;
            var success = await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file, options);

            if (success)
            {
                //File Launched
            }
            else
            {
                //File Launch Failed
            }
        }
    }
```

Call:

```
    await OpenFileWithAsync(...);
```

Comment: Tried your answer without success. Could it be that the file is in the local folder?

Comment: @DevelopingBeaver, it could. Access to file system is strictly regulated for UWP apps (see the [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) section of the documentation). Just for a test, place your PDF file somewhere your app will have no problems reaching it from (e.g. in _Pictures_ folder and add _PicturesLibrary_ capability to the manifest of your app).

Comment: I've moved the process of downloading and storing a document form the Xamarin Portable project to the UWP project. This Dows open the open with prompt correctly.